# Creating a subfolder in a directory in c++ throws syntax error

Tags: c++

I’m trying to create a subdirectory with today’s date in a folder. The code compiles succesfully, but throws an error during runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    // First create the directory with username
    if (mkdir("Anita_", 0777) == -1) 
        cerr << "Error :  " << strerror(errno) << endl; 
    else
        cout << "Directory created"; 
    
    //Pull out system date
    auto const now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto const in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%d_%m_%Y");
    
    //Prepare for subdirectory creating
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    string str_="mkdir -p Anita_/ss.str()";
    const char *com=str_.c_str();
    system(com);
    //system("mkdir -p Anita_/ss.str().c_str()");

}
```

During runtime I’m getting this error:

> sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Is it possible to use `mkdir()` instead of  `system()` , like `mkdir('Anita_/ss.str().c_str()', 0700);`

Comment: I presume you aren't trying to create a file called `Anita_/ss.str()`? That's what's in your string? [std::filesystem::create_directories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) would be a lot simpler

Comment: @AlanBirtles ss holds todays date. But Im unable to combine ss which is a variable with 'Anita_' which is constant (sorry but I come from python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put `ss.str()` inside double quotes and expect the shell to execute the C++ code.

Instead you should evaluate `ss.str()` in your program and pass the results to the shell

```
string str_ = "mkdir -p Anita_/" + ss.str();
const char *com = str_.c_str();
system(com);
```

This version uses `+` to append `"mkdir -p Anita_/"` and the result of `ss.str()` in your program **before** passing that command to the shell.

BTW there are two variables there you don't need, this one line of code does the same thing

```
system(("mkdir -p Anita_/" + ss.str()).c_str());
```

or if that seems a bit complicated you could do this

```
string str_ = "mkdir -p Anita_/" + ss.str();
system(str_.c_str());
```

which at least gets rid of one variable.

You don't have to use a variable everytime you call a function, you can call a function with an *expression*.

Comment: Great !! Im learning a lot , thanks a ton !!

Comment: what if I want to create a subdirectory -->  mkdir -p var1/ss.str( ); //Where var1 is a variable. I tried this but this creates var1/15_01_2021 , instead of anita/15_01_2021

Comment: @AnitaShukla You just have to do a similar thing to before, `var1` only means something in your code it doesn't mean anything special inside the string. Try this `string str_ = "mkdir -p " + var1 + "/" + ss.str();` (I'm assuming `var1` is a string variable).

Comment: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [10]’ and ‘char [80]’ to binary ‘operator+’  //If you want I cant open up a new question on this.

Comment: @AnitaShukla OK, like I said as was assuming that your variable was a string variable, but from the error message I see that its a char array. Simple fix, convert the `var1` char array to a string like this `string str_ = "mkdir -p " + string(var1) + "/" + ss.str();`

Comment: @AnitaShukla But really as a C++ programmer you should get out of the habit of using char arrays, they are almost never necessary, you should prefer string variables.